# LSTM and TimeseriesGenerator. Error in input shape

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

I try to follow online tutorials ([1](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-use-keras-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-data/), [2](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-the-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-forecasting-in-keras/) among others), but when fitting a LSTM model using keras `TimeseriesGenerator`, I cannot get the input dimensions right.

For training I have one long numpy array called `dn` of shape `(12499896,)`.
Then I define the keras `TimeseriesGenerator`

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
look_back = 10 
gen = TimeseriesGenerator(dn, dn, length=look_back, batch_size=8)
```

I define the model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=100, activation='relu', input_shape=(look_back, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

When I fit the model using `fit_generator`

```
model.fit_generator(gen, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=5)
```

I get the error:

> Error when checking input: expected lstm_9_input to have 3 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (8, 10)

If I understand correctly an `LSTM` requires input shape of `[samples, look_back, features]` (here I guess `samples=12499896`, `look_back=10`, and `features=1`). And `TimeseriesGenerator` produces a list of 2-tuples. Should I reshape the output of TimeseriesGenerator? (but I think it is not meant to be changed?). Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You have answered to your question, but I found few mistakes and would like to correct them.

When you are specifying `input_shape` for LSTM or any layer in  Keras, you need not mention the `batch_size`. So in case of LSTM, the input shape should be `[look_back, features]`. The more correctly used word for `look_back` is `timesteps`.

Since the input is one dimensioned data, you can reshape your data as you have done it which is:

```
dn = np.reshape(dn, (-1, 1))
```

Also, `return_sequences` in `LSTM` layer is False by default.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that it works if I first reshape the array

```
dn = np.reshape(dn, (len(dn),1))
```

so its shape is `(12499896, 1)` instead of `(12499896,)`.
Then in the LSTM layer use `return_sequences=False`:

```
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=False, activation='relu', input_shape=(look_back, 1)))
```